# How to use a separate file for IE responsive.css for version 10/11 in Drupal

Tags: theming

I am setting responsive design for only IE (Internet Explorer) in Drupal 7.
here is my code its for work lower then IE 10 not for IE 10/11

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/ie_10.css', 
    array('group' => CSS_THEME, 
        'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 10', 
            '!IE' => FALSE),
                 'preprocess' => FALSE)
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest customising a pre-built theme template that has already taken care of that such as [Zen](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen) or [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega).

Comment: our client demand using bootstrap